# Windows 10/Outook 2016

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I am a latecomer to PCs. Because of restricted time on my laptop I have a large inbox.  In the previous Outlook version I could manage this reasonably well in two stages 
(1) grouping emails by **From** or other filters and 
(2) moving selected multiple emails from each group to appropriate Folders I had created in Outlook, facilitated by the Inbox page number sequence ( 1,2,3 ...15 or whatever) appearing below the list of emails in view.  This allowed more rapid access than scrolling down several hundred - sometime thousands - of emails.

Have I missed a trick in my current (pre 365 version) of Outlook by not discovering ways of achieving a similar result ?   And is Outlook 365 any more help in providing an easy, say two-stage, way of sorting  a large inbox?  Grateful for any insights and suggestions.

Comment: What is the "Inbox page number sequence"? I feel this might be the key part of your question that I'm not understanding. Please EDIT your question to clarify this. You can still group messages, move them en bulk, and filter. Also, please limit each post to a single question so that we can get you a single good answer.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, Outlook doesn't have page number in message list. If you want to sort emails via “From”, you can select following filter option at the top of your inbox and choose “From”.

[image]

Or, you can also click View tab and choose From in the Arrangement group.
[image]

To move specific emails to specific folder, we can use Outlook rules. With rules, we can move an item from a certain sender or with certain words in the subject line to another folder automatically. Please refer to the details in this article: [Manage email messages by using rules](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-email-messages-by-using-rules-c24f5dea-9465-4df4-ad17-a50704d66c59)

Besides, we can also create search folder to show important emails that you want to check frequently. Reference: [Use Search Folders to find messages or other Outlook items](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-search-folders-to-find-messages-or-other-outlook-items-c1807038-01e4-475e-8869-0ccab0a56dc5)